# Executing queries by reading from files using python cx_oracle module

Tags: sql, python-2.7, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute sql and pl/sql queries by reading sql files in my folder using Python in an Oracle database. I am using cx_oracle module. I am unable to filter the sql and pl/sql queries as that have different syntax formats. Plz help me on this.

Comment: *I am unable to filter the sql and pl/sql queries*...please show the attempted code demonstrating this inability with example sql files. Also, if you connect to Oracle, all its dialect including SQL and PL/SQL should be available.

Comment: What are 'PL/SQL queries'? (And does it make a difference to your question?)

Comment: yes it does make a difference